# Print data instead of alert

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs, facebook-fql

I use the javascript to get some data from facebook using javascript sdk:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '111164862286924', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
/****************************************/

FB.api('/f8', function(response) {
  alert(response.company_overview);
});

/****************************************/
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
```

This code works fine but if I change alert with documen.write to print the data instead of showing it inside the popup window it doesn't seem to work any more. It doesn't print anything. Can anyone please tell what could be the reason?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `document.write` after the initial parse of the page is complete. Fortunately, though, there's no particular reason to.

If you have an element on the page and you wish to append to it, you can do this:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('theId');
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = "This is the <em>new content</em>.";
parent.appendChild(p);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ugero3/2) (It doesn't have to be an `p` element, it can be a `div` or `span` or anything else that's a valid child of the parent element.)

Note that if you just want to append to the bottom of the document (relatively rare, but hey), you can just use `document.body` in place of `parent`:

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = "This is the new content.";
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Similarly, if you want to *replace* the content of an element, just get a reference to it (using `getElementById` is a convenient way if the element has an ID, but there are other ways) and update it, rather than append to it:

```
var target = document.getElementById('targetId');
target.innerHTML = "This is the <em>updated content</em>.";
```

---

More re `document.write`: `document.write` actually writes to the HTML stream being parsed by the HTML parser. Naturally, once the page rendering is complete, there's no longer an HTML stream being parsed. But the DOM methods above are available for manipulating content on the page after the page is rendered.

---

**Off-topic**: DOM manipulation and DOM searching (finding elements to update) are both made easier (and in particular made easier cross-browser) if you use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) which will have syntactic sugar and workarounds for browser eccentricities, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to just output the value for testing. I recommend Console.JS for IE and Firebug for Firefox. They support a function called `console.log()` which will trace output to a debugging window.